# Printing a string with the parentheses attched

Tags: python, string

I am trying to print a string with the quotation marks around it. I am *NOT* using interactive mode here. So, I am trying to find out that is there any other way to do this other than:

```
print '"hello"'
```

or:

```
print "'hello'"
```

Is there a way to print a string with the quotation marks still attached to it? For example, if my string was `"Python"`, the result would be `"Python"` instead of `Python`, without the parentheses attached.

Comment: You mean you want the string *representation*? Something you can paste back into the Python interpreter and have it see it as a string literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> print repr(s)
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

In interactive mode, this is exactly how strings are printed:

```
>>> 'hello'
'hello'
```